# Display problems with Windows Media player

Tags: windows, video, troubleshooting, windows-media-player

ocasionally I run into a video that doesn't have the proper colors on play back when viewing on my machine, but it works fine on others computers. Any one have sugestions what may be goin wrong here?

Comment: Which video player are you using, and what version? Have you installed any codecs or codec packs? What is the file type of the video?... No, wait, I will try to use my psychic powers and say... .WMV right? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reinstalling the video drivers. Also, are your color set to 16 bit or higher? They should be set to 32 bit, perhaps 24 if that' all your video card does.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem with .WMV files when using YUV video mixing on some hardware.

In your media player options, look for a setting similar to "Use YUV mixing" and disable it.
You will not loose performance and video quality will not be affected. (YUV mixing is intended to provide clearer closed captions when outputting to TV)

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't getting any image at all I'd say that you were missing a codec, but that wouldn't just getting the colours wrong.

Are the errors consistent, or is it random? Do any other applications that display graphics (e.g. image editors) have the same problem?

I can only offer a few suggestions of things to try - I don't know whether any of them will work.

- Check that you have the latest versions of the video codecs.
- As emgee suggests check your video drivers, that they are up to date and what mode they are running in.
- Check that your video cable connectors are correctly seated and the cable is undamaged.
- Check that your video card is correctly seated in the motherboard.

Though these last two would produce more general errors.